# Magento: How to print quantity added to cart in success message?

Tags: php, jquery, magento, prototypejs

On Magento's product page, I have customized the success message that appears after clicking "Add to Cart". What I would like to do is display the quantity just added to the beginning of the message, to read like so:

> X Product Name was added to your shopping cart.

Is there a Mage helper that can print the value of X?

To clarify, I'm not looking for the snippets to print total cart/item quantities; rather, the variable quantity that was just added successfully. Any help fetching this value from the post data would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like `3 Test Products added to your shopping cart ?`. You can do this from `cartController` `addAction` method.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy, correct. That is the result I am seeking. Thank you for the comment; but I am still stuck. Does the solution you refer to involve creating an override module in app/code/local? Or is there a snippet that can print this quantity variable in the php file?

Comment: If you have overriden the file, you can use `$params['qty']` to fetch the added quantity of any product

Comment: Where you want to show this message ? product page | cart page ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt, I'm working in Messages.php to customize the success message that appears on both pages, product and cart (when an upsell is added). I can add, `$count = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();` and display the total # of items; but to get the added quantity, `$params['qty']` is returning blank. @Slimshadddyyy, can you elaborate on your suggestion, please? Thank you.